# Can I apply restrictions on jQuery Week Calendar plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, calendar

I use the [jQuery Week Calendar](https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar/) to handle the reservations in a gym. The problem is the gym use 45 minuntes length timeframes. If a user reserve he can start it at 07:15 or 08:00 or 08:45 or 09:30, etc.

Is there any way to apply restrictions on reservation?

Comment: might consider switching to a calendar that has documentation and support for setting event duration  ...look at fullCalendar  http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/  Docs have `slotMinutes` option. Also has support on this site

Comment: I need to use this week calendar software...

Comment: not sure what that means...fullcalendar supports month/week/day views and is very customizable and has a good API

Comment: if must stick with what you have...link you provided is to old fork no longer supported, there is another version and on main page has a google groups support link. Going to have a hard time getting much help for a plugin that has no documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my [DEMO LINK](http://www.dropbox.com/s/jam2i3vy9u6kooy/jquery.weekcalendar.rar)  where i have change logic of

```
 getTimeslotTimes : function(date) { }
```

in `jquery.weekcalendar.js` file as per my requirement .

So you can change this function as you want (45 minute) time slot .